# How to use NER tagging with spark corenlp?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Could you please provide example of stanford corenlp??
Please provide in Scala as I need to use it in spark shell.
All examples provided on the website are given in Java

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should try that in scala and if you find some difficulty to do, search in google, and then in SO finally post specific question in SO not some generic questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import com.databricks.spark.corenlp.functions._

import sqlContext.implicits._

val input = Seq(
  (1, "<xml>Stanford University is located in California. It is a great university.</xml>")
).toDF("id", "text")

val output = input
  .select(cleanxml('text).as('doc))
  .select(explode(ssplit('doc)).as('sen))
  .select('sen, tokenize('sen).as('words), ner('sen).as('nerTags), sentiment('sen).as('sentiment))

output.show(truncate = false)
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way of using it on an rdd instead of a dataframe?